# How to swap 2 divs onclick the links when divs are coming from loop in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some divs coming from loop and json. Here again I have 2 divs inside the main divs. initially 'show table' and chart1 should show only.when I click on 'show table', 'show chart' and table1 should only show and 'show table' and chart1 should hide.Same thing should happen for table when I click on 'show chart'.That should be happen based on each div.Here is the code below,I am new to angular 7 can anyone please help me.

### app.component.html

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px;border:1px solid; height:200px;width:200px;" class="list" *ngFor="let x of array">
 <div (click) ="showChart()" ><strong>show chart</strong></div>
  <div (click) ="showTable()"><strong>show table</strong></div>
  <div>{{x.chart}}</div>
  <div>{{x.table}}</div>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
    import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
        public array = [{"id":1,"chart":"chart1","table":"table1"},{"id":2,"chart":"chart2","table":"table2"},{"id":2,"chart":"chart3","table":"table3"}];
 showChart(){
      alert("chart");
   }
   showTable(){
      alert("table");
   }
```

Comment: use ngIf. store current state of chart visibility and table visibilty as bools and toggle them onclick

Comment: So add a variable in your component indicating which of the two divs should be shown, and user *ngIf on the two divs to only show the div when the variable has a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which you need to do.

In your data structure, maintain flags to show table and chart as

```
{"id":1,"chart":"chart1","table":"table1", "showTable": true, "showChart": true}
```

Use these boolean flags to maintain the state of show and hide as

```
<div (click)="x.showChart = !x.showChart"><strong>show chart</strong></div>
```

and use this in your `*ngIf` directive as

```
<div *ngIf="x.showChart">{{x.chart}}</div>
```

I would prefer to use `[class]` binding to show and hide the div as

```
<div [class.active]="x.showChart">{{x.chart}}</div>
```

where class `active` will show the element on the page otherwise hidden

Answer (score 0):

Without touching the data of the original  `array`, you can easily solve this by creating a second array to keep track of the visibility of individual items.

In your `AppComponent` simply place this attribute:

```js
public visibility = [];
```

And use it in your template like so:

```html
<div style="..." class="list" *ngFor="let x of array">
  <div (click)="visibility[x.id] = 'chart'"><strong>show chart</strong></div>
  <div (click)="visibility[x.id] = 'table'"><strong>show table</strong></div>
  <div *ngIf="visibility[x.id] === 'chart'">{{x.chart}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="visibility[x.id] === 'table'">{{x.table}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-btvfcw

Note that in your `app.component.ts`, the second and third item had the same id `2`. I fixed it.

---

Edit: You can also make the buttons toggle the current view, if you want:

```html
  <div (click)="visibility[x.id] = (visibility[x.id] === 'chart' ? '' : 'chart')"><strong>show chart</strong></div>
  <div (click)="visibility[x.id] = (visibility[x.id] === 'table' ? '' : 'table')"><strong>show table</strong></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but button toggle is not happening here,I added this code, also on page load chart1,char2,chart3 should be visible along with 'show table' button.